# Checking adjacent cells in Excel in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to check each pair of cells (A1 and B1, A2 and B2) etc in a range (A1:B35). Each cell in columns A and B contains either an "R" or "J". Putting A and B together, each row could read "RR", "RJ", "JJ", or "JR". I need to keep track of the rows each of those 4 combinations appear in. Is there a simple formula I can use to do this?

Comment: Will columns A and B *only* contain R or J, or will they be part of a bigger string?  And how exactly do you want to "track" the rows?  Clarify the question a bit, maybe post expected input and output.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of if limited to formulas:

- In C1, put `=A1&B1`, and then fill down.
- In D1, put `=If(C1="RR",Row(C1),"")`, and then fill down.
- In E1, put `=If(C1="RJ",Row(C1),"")`, and then fill down.
- In F1, put `=If(C1="JR",Row(C1),"")`, and then fill down.
- In G1, put `=If(C1="JJ",Row(C1),"")`, and then fill down.
- In D36, put `=CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(D1:D35))`, but before pushing Enter, select the Transpose portion of the code and push F9.
- Remove the curly brackets from the result.
- Push enter.
- Repeat for E36, F36, and G36.

Concatenate-transpose technique from: http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/